# Getting the values from multiple drop down boxs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, drop-down-menu

I want to get the value of the three drop down boxes so it will be displayed somewhere else when the button is clicked.

I googled this a lot and found a post where someone used day.options[day.selectedIndex].value; and it worked perfectly but when i tried it then it managed to pick up that i was trying to read the values (which is further than i had gotten before i tried this method) but it would just return Day:day   Month:month   Year:year as opposed to the actual values of each. Im assuming the problem comes in because of the for loops within all the drop down boxes but i have no idea how to fix it.

```
 function Age(gender){
        if (gender!==undefined){
            el1 = document.getElementById('userdata');
            el1.innerHTML += gender +"<br>";    
        }
        el1 = document.getElementById('farespage');
        var month = 1;
        var day = 1;
        var year = 2002; 
        var newHTML = "";
            newHTML +="<div id=\"ageheading\">Date of Birth</div><div id=\"agebox\"><div class=\"innerage\" onclick=\"Relationship('"+day+"')\">Day<select id=\"dropdownday\">";
        for(var day; day<=31; day++){
            newHTML +="<option value=\"day\">"+day+"</option>"};
            newHTML +="</select></div><div class=\"innerage\">Month<select id=\"dropdownmonth\">";
        for(var month; month<=12; month++){
            newHTML +="<option value=\"month\">"+month+"</option>"};
            newHTML +="</select></div><div class=\"innerage\">Year<select id=\"dropdownyear\">";
        for(var year; year>=1920; year--){
            newHTML +="<option value=\"year\">"+year+"</option>"};
            newHTML +="</select></div><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"goback('Gender')\">back</button><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"dob()\">Enter</button></div>";
            el1.innerHTML += newHTML;
    }

    function dob(){
        var day = document.getElementById("dropdownday");
        var dayoptions = day.options[day.selectedIndex].value;
        var month = document.getElementById("dropdownmonth");
        var monthoptions = month.options[month.selectedIndex].value;
        var year = document.getElementById("dropdownyear");
        var yearoptions = year.options[year.selectedIndex].value;
        var birthday = '<div>Day: ' + dayoptions + '</div>' + '<div>Month: ' + monthoptions + '</div>' + '<div>Year: ' + yearoptions + '</div>';
        el1 = document.getElementById("userdata");
        el1.innerHTML += birthday;
        window['Relationship']();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make a slight fix in your Age function:

```
function Age(gender){
    if (gender!==undefined){
        el1 = document.getElementById('userdata');
        el1.innerHTML += gender +"<br>";    
    }
    el1 = document.getElementById('farespage');
    var month = 1;
    var day = 1;
    var year = 2002; 
    var newHTML = "";
        newHTML +="<div id=\"ageheading\">Date of Birth</div><div id=\"agebox\"><div class=\"innerage\" onclick=\"Relationship('"+day+"')\">Day<select id=\"dropdownday\">";
    for(var day; day<=31; day++){
        newHTML +="<option value=\""+day+"\">"+day+"</option>"};
        newHTML +="</select></div><div class=\"innerage\">Month<select id=\"dropdownmonth\">";
    for(var month; month<=12; month++){
        newHTML +="<option value=\""+month+"\">"+month+"</option>"};
        newHTML +="</select></div><div class=\"innerage\">Year<select id=\"dropdownyear\">";
    for(var year; year>=1920; year--){
        newHTML +="<option value=\""+year+"\">"+year+"</option>"};
        newHTML +="</select></div><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"goback('Gender')\">back</button><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"dob()\">Enter</button></div>";
        el1.innerHTML += newHTML;
}
```

Basically replace value=\"day\">" with: value=\""+day+"\">" and the same for year and month.

Comment: Ah all that for the simplest answer in the world. You sir are a legend